# pandas .loc returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe, which looks like below.

```
chainage(km)  
0  
0.001  
0.002  
0.003  
0.004
```

while I use `.loc` to search for the `chainage(km)` it returns the empty dataframe for some chainages.

```
print data.loc[data['chainage(km)'] == float(0.004)]
```

-- Empty dataframe

```
print data.loc[data['chainage(km)'] == float(0.001)]
```

-- returns value

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you put the output of `data['chainage(km)'].dtype` & `data['chainage(km)'] - float(0.004)` in your post

Comment: Hi Haleemur, Yep when I subtract with 0.004, then output is not 0. it is floating point math broken issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises due to floating point inaccuracies. This is explained in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

In situations like this, please use `np.isclose` instead.

```
df[np.isclose(data['chainage(km)'], 0.004)]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Two possible causes:*

It is possible that the column `chainage(km)` is an object type, and for the fifth row it stores `0.004` as a string, i.e. `'0.004'`. To fix that cast it as float

```
data = data.astype(float)
```

If after doing the above casting, the filtering still doesn't work for `0.004`

Then, given that `data['chainage(km)'] == float(0.004)` doesn't return any `True`, while `data.loc[data['chainage(km)'] == float(0.001)]` returns correctly, it suggest that you are experiencing floating point errors.

Try the following:

```
x = float(0.004)
data[abs(data['chainage(km)'] - float(x)) < 0.0001*x]
```

This filters for the row replacing the equality condition with an arbitrarily sized error.